# Updated Image not getting reflected

Tags: java, ajax, file, crop

I am trying to crop image.There is an ajax call made to the server end where cropping takes place and original file gets replaced with cropped image.
Now when i get back the control, i still see the old image even though cropped image exists at the same location.

Changes reflect only after page refresh which i don't want users to do it.Code for crop image is as follows

```
            BufferedImage originalImgage = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath+"\\"+subFolder+"\\"+fileName));
            ImageIO.write(originalImgage,extention,new File(filePath+"\\"+subFolder+"\\"+dateStamp+"_"+fileName));//save original image

            BufferedImage SubImgage = originalImgage.getSubimage(xAxis,yAxis,width,height); 

            File outputfile = new File(filePath+"\\"+subFolder+"\\"+fileName);

            ImageIO.write(SubImgage,extention,outputfile);
```

pls help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the image src parameter with the new path returned from ajax in ajax success call back.

Answer (score 0):

Well after struggling a lot finally found the problem.The image is cached by the browser. So whenever u do any operations on image on the same file location , the latest copy is not download.Instead old image from cache is still referred.

Hence the solution was to make browser download latest copy.This was simple.
Append dummy parameter to file path forcing browser to download
    `rand =  new Date().getTime();`

```
var image_Path = filePath+"?crop="+rand
```